# Facebook Mobile-Web Ad Display Issues

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-ads-api, iphone-web-app, facebook-audience-network

I am using Facebook Audience Network(MobileWeb-beta) for ads on my mobile site. But the 320x50 html source code doesn't display the add across the width of the mobile screen as it should, it displays a smaller ad(as shown in the image).

I am using the code given on Fb site:
`<div class="fb-ad" data-placementid="xxxxxx-xxxxxx" data-format="320x50" data-testmode="true">
</div>`

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

[Ad display Phone Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eov2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your viewport set? Adding this to your `<head>` should fix it.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very appreciated.
But I am using `window.innerWidth` to get width of the screen using this changes the value of that.